# Assigning Grades using an Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have my results in `Column9` and I have to assign a grade for each student in `Column 10`.  This is my Excel macro code.

```
Sub grading()
Dim k As Integer
Dim result As String
For k = 2 To 6
If (Cells(k, 9) >= 75) Then
   result = "A"

ElseIf (Cells(k, 9) >= 65) Then
  result = "B"

ElseIf (Cells(k, 9) >= 55) Then
   result = "C"

Else
   result = "F"
End If

Cells(i, 10).Value = result
Next k
End Sub
```

But this gives a run-time error:

> Application defined or object- defined error.

What is wrong with this. This is my first macro so I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sam_rox.

There is a small error in your code :

```
Cells(i, 10).Value = result
```

Should be :

```
Cells(k, 10).Value = result
```

Seems to work fine after this modification.